# Running into a Multithreading issue connecting to multiple devices at the same time

Tags: python, multithreading

I am defining the main function with `def get_info()`. This function doesn't take the arguments. This program uses `argumentParser` to parse the arguments from the command line. The argument provided is the CSV file with `--csv` option. This picks up the csv file from the current directory and read the lines each containing an IP address, logs into devices serially and runs few commands return the output and appends in the text file. When the code runs it removes the old text file from the directory and create a new output text file when executed.
Problem: I want to achieve this using threading module so that it takes 5 devices in parallel and outputs to a file. The problem I am running is with the lock issues as the same object is being used by same process at the same time. Here the sample code I have written. The threading concept is very new to me so please understand.

import getpass
import csv
import time
import os
import netmiko
import paramiko
from argparse import ArgumentParser
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

def get_ip(device_ip,output_q):

```
        try:
            ssh_session = netmiko.ConnectHandler(device_type='cisco_ios', ip=device_row['device_ip'],
                                                 username=ssh_username, password=ssh_password)
            time.sleep(2)
            ssh_session.clear_buffer()
        except (netmiko.ssh_exception.NetMikoTimeoutException,
                netmiko.ssh_exception.NetMikoAuthenticationException,
                paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException) as s_error:
            print(s_error)
```

def main():

```
show_vlanfile = "pool.txt"
if os.path.isfile(show_vlanfile):
  try:
    os.remove(show_vlanfile)
  except OSError as e:
    print("Error: %s - %s." %(e.filename, e.strerror))

parser = ArgumentParser(description='Arguments for running oneLiner.py')
parser.add_argument('-c', '--csv', required=True, action='store', help='Location of CSV file')             
args = parser.parse_args()                                                                                 

ssh_username = input("SSH username: ")                                                                     
ssh_password = getpass.getpass('SSH Password: ')                                                           

with open(args.csv, "r") as file:                                                                          
    reader = csv.DictReader(file)                                                                          
    output_q = Queue(maxsize=5)                                                                            
    procs = []                                                                                             
    for device_row in reader:                                                                              
       # print("+++++ {0} +++++".format(device_row['device_ip']))                                          
         my_proc = Process(target=show_version_queue, args=(device_row, output_q))                         
         my_proc.start()                                                                                   
         procs.append(my_proc)                                                                             

# Make sure all processes have finished                                                                    
    for a_proc in procs:                                                                                   
        a_proc.join()                                                                                      

            commands = ["terminal length 0","terminal width 511","show run | inc hostname","show ip int brief | ex una","show
```

vlan brief","terminal length 70"]
                output = ''
                for cmd in commands:
                   output += "\n"
                   output += ssh_session.send_command(cmd)
                   output += "\n"
                   with open("pool.txt", 'a') as outputfile:
                   while not output_q.empty():
                   output_queue = output_q.get()
                   for x in output_queue:
                       outputfile.write(x)

if **name** == "**main**":
    main()

Answer (score 1):

Somewhat different take...

I run effectively a main task, and then just fire up a (limited) number of threads; and they communicate via 2 data queues - basically "requests" and "responses".

Main task

- dumps the requests into the request queue.
- fires up a number (i.e. 10 or so...) worker tasks.
- sits on the "response" queue waiting for results.  The results can be simple user info messages about status, error messages, or DATA responses to be written out to files.
- When all the threads finish, program shuts down.

Workers basically:

- get a request.  If none, just shut down
- connect to the device
- send a log message to the response queue that it's started.
- does what it has to do.
- puts the result as DATA to the response queue
- closes the connection to the device
- loop back to the start

This way you don't inadvertently flood the processing host, as you have a limited number of concurrent threads going, all doing exactly the same thing in their own sweet time, until there's nothing left to do.

Note that you DON'T do any screen/file IO in the threads, as it will get jumbled with the different tasks running at the same time.  Each essentially only sees inputQ, outputQ, and the Netmiko sessions that get cycled through.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have code that is from a Django example:

```
def main():
    '''
    Use threads and Netmiko to connect to each of the devices in the database.
    '''
    devices = NetworkDevice.objects.all()
```

You should move the argument parsing into the main thread. You should read the CSV file in the main thread. You should have each child thread be the Netmiko-SSH connection.

I say this as your current solution--has all of the SSH connections happen in one thread which is not what you intended.

At a high-level main() should have argument parsing, delete old output file, obtain username/password (assuming these are the same for all the devices), loop over CSV file obtaining the IP address for each device.

Once you have the IP address, then you create a thread, the thread uses Netmiko-SSH to connect to each device and retrieve your output. I would then use a Queue to pass back the output from each device (back to the main thread).

Then back in the main thread, you would write all of the output to a single file.

It would look a bit like this:

https://github.com/ktbyers/netmiko/blob/develop/examples/use_cases/case16_concurrency/threads_netmiko.py

Here is an example using a queue (with multiprocessing) though you can probably adapt this using a thread-Queue pretty easily.

https://github.com/ktbyers/netmiko/blob/develop/examples/use_cases/case16_concurrency/processes_netmiko_queue.py

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am new to python and learning. When you say retrieve the IP from CSV and create a thread, could you please provide me the snippet of code as how would the code look like as this will help me build on that. I have never done threading previously which leads me to more confusion.

Comment: As per your instructions I have amended the code, but doesn't seem correct. Could you please go over and let me know if this needs any correction. I have edited the main code and pasted over it. Thanks in advance.